# How do I build up reputation and get feedback on answers/posts?

Tags: discussion, support

When I joined this community I answered a question. someone commented on it. before I could respond it got deleted.

[What do you say to a woman who asks you to dance when you don’t want to?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/545/what-do-you-say-to-a-woman-who-asks-you-to-dance-when-you-don-t-want-to)

I dance socially every week so I know how to turn down a dance If I don't want to and I think I could have explained my viewpoint well.

Because I didn't have enough rep I couldn't ask about it here on meta. (you can only ask about your own posts not ones you've answered)

and I asked a question but that got put on hold.
[hobby vs creating a business boundary](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11372/hobby-vs-creating-a-business-boundary)

I'm a newbie here so I'm a bit confused by whats gone on.

**Edit:**

I've now edited My first answer to when you can turn down a dance. If that can be undeleted that would be great.

Comment: just as an FYI, the best way to get an answer undeleted after editing the problems is to flag it for moderator attention.  Deleted answers don't come up in any sort of moderation queue, so unless someone is seeking them out, we usually don't see them very easily.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From checking out your StackExchange profile, I can see that you're not new to the StackExchange Q&A model. To answer your title question in the most direct, yet unhelpful, way "You earn rep and get feedback in the same way as any other SE site."

I'm not sure about your answer, but based on your question, I suspect that you may be facing an issue that we are grappling with in that: **Your assumption of what the purpose of/topic of IPS.stackexchange and what this site's community deems on-topic may not be aligned.**

"Interpersonal Skills" is a term that definitely allows for some ambiguity in how an individual interprets what qualifies as on-topic.

Some of this disparity can probably be cleared up by [Taking the tour](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour) and reading through the [Help section](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help). You may also want to look around the meta section, as the definition of on-topic IPS vs off-topic (and probably flagged/downvoted/deleted/locked) is still a work in progress.

In the case of your question, users did provide feedback in the comments, if their feedback isn't clear enough, you could always try asking around [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) for clarification. I believe that your question can be re-framed and focused a bit more after you read the [On-Topic](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of [the help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help).

A question being on hold means that moderators have deemed the question not good enough to allow answers, **but the question may have the potential be improved and the reopened.** On-hold questions are not a lost cause (those get deleted), the question just needs work from the Asker to resolve the issue before allowing further voting or answering to take place.